# Storing unique values in django hstorefield with postgresql

Tags: django, postgresql

Is it possible to add a postgresql hstorefield (django >= 1.8) to a model where values in the hstore are unique?
Keys are obviously unique but can values be unique as well? I suppose custom validators could be added to the model but I am curious to know if this can be done on the database level

Comment: Define "unique" for this purpose. Is the *set of values* unique? Is the set of key/value combinations unique? Is the value of one particular key unique? Show examples of what should and should not be allowed please - edit the question then comment here when done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single `hstore` value can contain multiple `key => value` pairs, making a solution based on a unique index impossible. Additionally, your new `hstore` value can also have multiple `key => value` pairs. The only viable alternative is then a `BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE` trigger on the table:

```
CREATE FUNCTION trf_uniq_hstore_values() RETURNS trigger AS $$
DECLARE
  dups text;
BEGIN
  SELECT string_agg(x, ',') INTO dups
  FROM (SELECT svals(hstorefield) AS x FROM my_table) sub
  JOIN (SELECT svals(NEW.hstorefield) AS x) vals USING (x);

  IF dups IS NOT NULL THEN
    RAISE NOTICE format('Value(s) %s violate(s) uniqueness constraint. Operation aborted.', dups);
    RETURN NULL;
  ELSE
    RETURN NEW;
  END IF;
END; $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER tr_uniq_hstore_values
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON my_table
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE trf_uniq_hstore_values();
```

Note that this will not trap existing duplicates in the table.

Comment: I do understand now why this is impossible, as key-value pairs do not have the same privileges are regular fields in the eyes of the relational model. The offered solution is good, but I would rather validate in Python using the ORM since its easier for me to write/maintain such code even if, performance-wise, its better to do on the DB level. Thank you

Comment: You can use a `UNIQUE` expression index  if you also add a `CHECK` constraint that prevents more than one instance of that key within a single `hstore` field.